# How to get the object that is selected from a jList

Tags: java, database, netbeans, bind, jlist

I build a Java project at Netbeans.
I have a Form and inside the Form i have a jList that is populated with an object (Favorite).
I have also a Button and i want when i press the Button to Delete the selected item at jList.

I am trying the following code but i get an error.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    int selectedIndex = jList1.getSelectedIndex();
    ListModel lModel= jList1.getModel();
    Favorite item = (Favorite)lModel.getElementAt(selectedIndex);
    System.out.println("name= "+ item.getName());   
}
```

I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to model.FavoriteList
>       at my.mymoviesamn.FavoriteTestForm.jButton1ActionPerformed(FavoriteTestForm.java:104)
>       at my.mymoviesamn.FavoriteTestForm.access$000(FavoriteTestForm.java:15)
>       at my.mymoviesamn.FavoriteTestForm$1.actionPerformed(FavoriteTestForm.java:51)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)

What is the problem?
When i select an item from the jList i want to get that object (Favorite) and Delete it.
The problem is i can not get that object from jList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Favorite item = (Favorite)lModel.getElementAt(selectedIndex);
```

You assume that your model contains `Favorite` objects. It does **not**. It contains Strings.

So other parts of your code that **fill** that model are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create separate Empty `List` and insert objects in it which are selected before deleting it.

As `ClassCastException` come you need to check what is the type of itms under ListModel it must be a `String` thats why you are getting this error.

You should make custom ListModel like below:

```
class ListModel extends AbstractListModel {
  private Favorite mfavorite;

  public ListModel(Favorite favorite) {
    mfavorite = favorite;
  }

  public Favorite getFavorite() {
    return mfavorite;
  }

  public Object getElementAt(Favorite favorite) {
    return favorite;
  }
}
```